# Not able to find sporadic SIGABRT error! How to find cause?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, exception

I am looking already for hours to find the root cause of this sporadic exception I am getting. I happens in the simulator when I present a view controller modally. It happens between the 5-15th segue I do... I can sort of reproduce it, by going back and forward between my segues... There are no leaks (checked with instruments) Any ideas how I can find the loc where the error could appear... the stack trace does not give me any clue!

> 2014-05-05 18:08:07.095 [9882:60b] Preparing for segue to view
>   controller: BCPhotoBrowserViewController 2014-05-05 18:08:19.541
>   [9882:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001033ad495 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010259399e objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010343168e __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 126   3   UIKit
>   0x000000010119438c -[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 321   4   UIKit                               0x00000001011944ef
>   __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke
>   + 116     5   UIKit                               0x00000001011943fe -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 435  6   UIKit                               0x000000010119e031
>   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 873  7   UIKit                               0x000000010141b778
>   -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 454   8   UIKit                               0x000000010141b5b0
>   -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 25     9   UIKit                               0x00000001012584d7 -[UINavigationController
>   _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2893     10  UIKit                               0x0000000101258787
>   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 547     11  UIKit                               0x0000000101259238
>   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43   12  UIKit                               0x0000000101373895 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202    13 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000114a24040
>   -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) layoutSubviews] + 43   14  UIKit                               0x00000001011a0993
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354  15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001031d6802 -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 151    16  QuartzCore
>
>   0x00000001031cb369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
>   363   17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001031cb1ea
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010313efb8
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252   19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000103140030
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010314069d
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89     21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103378dc7
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103378d37
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391  23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103358522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946     24  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000103357d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     25  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000104504f04 GSEventRunModal + 161  26  UIKit
>   0x0000000101140e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010   27
>   0x00000001000e41b5 main + 245     28  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000103d355fd start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: You are modifying a collection while you're enumerating it. That's the issue.

Comment: Ok sure... and its probably not in the controllers directly, but in one of the subclasses... Any way to find out easily exactly where it crashes?

Comment: Ben if I was a betting man I would say you are modifying your collection of photos while enumerating when trying to segue to BCPhotoBrowserViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Larme is right in the comments, somewhere in your code you are doing something to your collection while you are enumerating. It would not come up in instruments, because it is not a leak, but a programming error while using collections.

Look for any adding, removing of objects to a collection while enumerating on that collection.

Comment: Sure so, I thought, there might be an easy way to find that line of code where the error is :/ ?

Comment: This line is very telling, you won't get what line in what class, but it can give you a very good idea where: Preparing for segue to view controller: BCPhotoBrowserViewController 2014-05-05 18:08:19.541 [9882:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '* Collection was mutated while being enumerated.'